# OO shopping cart class + product class interaction

Tags: php, object-oriented, e-commerce

I built a small store site for learning purposes. I loaded my 'products' from the db into a `Products` class.  I used a method from this class to display the products in HTML.  Of course, the HTML contains 'Add to Cart' buttons which POST the product ID and quantity when a button is clicked.  The result is that the POSTed ID and quantity are sent to the `Cart` class.  This works, but it seems like I should be sending a product **object** to my cart instead of just two values that will be stored in an array.

I'm not sure how to do that, given that product information needs to be POSTed non-objectively.  And I'm not sure if it would be better.

```
class Products
{

private $products; 

function __construct($data)
{

    $this->products = $data;

}   

public function showProduct($id, $price, $type)
{
        echo "<div id='$id' class='product'>";
        echo $type."<br/>";
        echo $price."<br/>";            
        echo "Quantity: <input class='quantity' name='quantity' value='1' type='text'/><br/>";
        echo "<button onclick='add($id);'>Add to Cart</button>";
        echo "</div>";      
}

public function showAll()
{
    foreach ($this->products as $id => $product) {

        $this->showProduct($id, $product->price, $product->type);
    }

}   



}
```

And the `Cart` class:

```
class Cart
{
public $items = array();

function __construct() {

    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) { $this->items = $_SESSION['cart']; } else { $_SESSION['cart'] = ''; }
}

private function update() {

    $_SESSION['cart'] = $this->items;
}   

public function add($id, $quantity) {

    $this->items[] = array('id'=>"$id", 'quantity'=>"$quantity");
    $this->update();

}
}
```

I'm not sure that I was able to get the objects from these classes to interact with each other properly.

Also, in this situation, since I need to use `$_SESSION` to keep the cart inventory persistent, I'm not sure why I need a `Cart` class at all.  It seems a little superfluous, but I have a nagging feeling that it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

I would have done it in the following way:

```
<?php
    class Product {
        private $id;
        private $type;
        private $price;


        public function __toString() {
            return  "your way to display the Product object ie: <p> The id is: $this->getId </p> ";
        }


        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }


        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;
        }

        public function getType()
        {
            return $this->type;
        }

        public function setType($type)
        {
            $this->type = $type;
        }

        public function getPrice()
        {
            return $this->price;
        }

        public function setPrice($price)
        {
            $this->price = $price;
        }

    }

    class Cart {
        private $products;
        private $id;

        public function getProducts()
        {
            return $this->products;
        }


        public function addProduct(Product $product)
        {
            $this->products[] = $product;
        }


        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }


        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the sum off all products prices
         * array_reduce docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php
         */
        public function total(){
            return array_reduce($this->getProducts(), function($carry, $product){
                return $carry + $product->getPrice();
            });
        }

    }
```

It's important to note here that you are managing objects, so you will need some [Object Relational Mapper](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/) to persist objects on a DB, such as Doctrine.

You need to separate concerns in a MVC architecture, the logic of your domain the 'M' of MVC (in this case the shopping cart) reside in a object model (Product + cart) . Then you need the 'C' here you tell the cart that you want to add a new product:

```
class Controller {
        public function someAction(){
            $product = new Product();
            $product->setId(1);
            $product->setPrice(100.00);
            $product->setType(3); //Id of the type

            $cart = new Cart;
            $cart->addProduct($product);

            $cart->total(); //Will return 100.00
            //Logic to obtain twig engine
            return $twig->render('Template', ['cart' => $cart]); //returns HTML
        }
    }
```

And finally the V of the MVC there is where you build your HTML:

Using a template engine like Twig:

```
     <html>
        <body>
        Total: {{cart.total()}}
           <ol>
              {% for product in cart.products %}
                 <li>{{product}}</li>
              {% else %}
                 <li>Empty cart</li>
              {% endfor %}
           </ol>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Of course building this architecture on your own could be really complicated there is when frameworks like symfony kick in http://symfony.com/. It's just a personal recommendation.

Also, take a look at OOP patterns. They will make your life easier and you will learn how to program good architectures for models.